# Extra sensory perception vs Artificial Intelligence

Tags: metaphysics

Will human extra sensory perception be ever replaced by artificial intelligence?

Comment: Turing doesn't seem to think so in "Computing Machinery and Intelligence", section 6.9 because he tries to protect against it, but one would have to provide an argument. Examples of extra sensory perception, or "psi", or "supernormal" behavior can be found in Dean Radin's "Select Psi Research Publications" http://deanradin.com/evidence/evidence.htm To the extent this involves modifying the behavior of photons in a double slit experiment I don't see how an AI machine, which is a Turing machine, would be able to do something like that although Radin has shown that humans can do that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. One-line posts are discouraged because it is hard to tell from them what people are looking for. Please explain what "human ESP" is and on what objective basis you wish us to answer the question. "What do you think" questions that invite personal opinions are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Kurzweil says *yes*; based on the size of the processors that are smaller each year or so. 
In his books like The Singularity is near he talks about these phenomena that, in his opinion, we are going to live to see this happen.

In my opinion, some people are already replacing senses or even organs thanks to technology.
Artificial Intelligences(plural) are already "helping" humankind in the daily life, maybe not with directly with senses(yet) but with tasks that give us more time to spend as we want, free time to enjoy our senses, to feel, to live.

Comment: It is clear what a computer running a program is, regardless of the size of its processors: It is a Turing machine. It is not clear what extra sensory perception is. That is what makes the question Drago asks difficult.  However, it is clear that ESP or psi exists.  So the question is relevant for AI.

Answer (score 0):

John Searle presented a thought experiment called the Chinese Room Argument (CRA) in “Minds, Brains and Programs” which showed that a Turing machine running a program should not be expected to understand language even if that machine passes a Turing test.

Assuming extra sensory perception is at least as difficult as understanding language or even that understanding language is a kind of psi activity, the CRA shows that artificial intelligence will not be able to exercise extra sensory perception either because it cannot understand language.

So, the answer is likely no depending on what extra sensory perception turns out to be.